Getting "Unable to resolve" error when trying to load .bin file in react-native expo
I am trying to use Tensorflow for one of my project, and i have two .bin files that i want to load locally. I added them in assets folder, and now using code like:
const modelWeights1 = await require('../../assets/group1-shard1of2.bin');

Getting this error:
Android Bundling failed 10951ms node_modules/expo-router/entry.js (1247 modules)
Unable to resolve "../..assets/group1-shard1of2.bin" from "app/(tabs)/poseview.tsx"

I have searched alot, most of the solutions were to add metro.config.js
metro.config.js:
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');
module.exports = (async () => {
  const defaultConfig = await getDefaultConfig();
  const { assetExts } = defaultConfig.resolver;
  return {
    resolver: {
      // Add bin to assetExts
      assetExts: [...assetExts, 'bin'],
    }
  };
})();

still its not working, I am getting the same issue.
I am using Expo 52

After trying to fix it for two days, i found out, I created metro.config.js manually, so I deleted it again and put below code in terminal


npx expo customize metro.config.js



this generates metro.config.js file for you in the root folder.
then pasted below code in the file


const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");
const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

// Added this line:
config.resolver.assetExts.push("bin");

module.exports = config;



and it started working
